# animate.css - 2 classes on 1 div

Tags: css, animation

I'm using animate.css for an easy animation. Works fine so far, but what I'm trying to archive is to add 2 classes/animations on one div with a delay.

fadeIn > 3 sec delay > fadeout

This is my div:

```
<div class="container fadeIn fadeOut">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

And this is my additional CSS to delay the fadeOut:

```
.fadeOut {
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 3s; }
```

What's happening now is that the div only fades out after 3 seconds, the fadeIn animation does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

both transitions will not work at same time, you have to add fade out in css with some kind of condition. i think this might be helpfull. OR tell me full scenario, i'll try my best to help.

Comment: they shall not happen at the same time, that's why i want a 3 second delay between them. fadeIn > 3 sec delay > fadeout

i tried to make it work with the css code i posted